# Browser crashes whenever read a large file using FileReader

Tags: javascript, filereader

I am trying to read a file using FileReader and post the file content to Java client but whenever size of the file goes big, browser crashes. Code snippet below

```
function submitMe(){
    document.getElementById("Form").fileContent.value = contents;
    document.getElementById("Form").fileName.value = document.getElementById("bicForm").fileName1.value;
    document.getElementById("Form").submit();
}
function readSingleFile(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 
    if (f) {
        var r = new FileReader();
        r.onload = function(e) { 
          contents = e.target.result;
        }
        r.readAsText(f);
    } else { 
        alert("Failed to load file");
    }

}
```

I cannot post partial content of the file to my Java client. How can I fix this issue. Is there a way wherein I can pass the FileStream object to Java client or some better way.

Comment: What do you mean by "Java ***client***"? Do you mean Java ***server***? E.g., servlet, JSP, something along those lines?

Comment: You did not describe how you communicate with the Java application. And of course trying to read a large file into memory is going to fail at some point. In order to help you we need to understand how you access the Java client and whether you control the Java client at all (you wrote it, you have its API?)

Comment: *"Is there a way wherein I can pass the FileStream object to Java client or some better way."* Well, you could...post a form to the server, which is a tried-and-true mechanism for streaming file data from browser to server.